# Using SUDO to execute a general command inside a non-accessible directory

Tags: directory, sudo

I want to grep something inside a directory. But the user doesn't have permissions in the directory. Because of some reasons, I am not allowed to change permissions, group or owner. Just want to know I can access that directory by some entry in the sudoers file.

```
grep -r "some phrase" /path/to/restricted-dir
```

Is there any way to execute the above command using sudo?

Comment: Umm... `sudo grep -r "some phrase" /path/to/restricted-dir`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that avoiding wildcards in `sudoers` (but getting a race condition instead which seems not to be a problem here, though) by putting the patterns in a file:

```
grep -r -f /path/to/file/with/patterns /path/to/restricted-dir
```

This can be put in `sudoers`.

Another solution is a wrapper script (which is put in `sudoers`):

```
sudo /wrapper/script pattern1 pattern2
```

The script would work like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
test $# -eq 0 && exit 0 # no arguments
index=0
pattern_args=()
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    pattern_args[index]="-e"
    ((index++))
    pattern_args[index]="$1"
    ((index++))
    shift
done
grep -r "${pattern_args[@]}" /path/to/restricted-dir
```